# Getting typecast error while creating dbcp2.PoolableConnection with dbcp 2.9 version and Ojdbc8

Tags: java, connection-pooling, ojdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

**Background** - I was using commons-dbcp 1.2 in my project and I am trying to upgrade to latest commons-dbcp2 2.9 version with ojdbc8 to achieve the resiliency that comes from newer dpcp2 version.

**Problem** - Post updating to newer dbcp2 I am getting issue while typecasting java.sql.Connection object to dbcp2.PoolableConnection. It is not allowing typecasting throwing below error.

```
 org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection
```

Below is my code that I am using.

```
        CallableStatement stmt;
        Connection connection = stmt.getConnection();

        PoolableConnection poolConn = (PoolableConnection) connection;
        OracleConnection nativeConnection = (OracleConnection) poolConn.getDelegate();
```

I tried to unwrap the connection like below

```
PoolableConnection poolConn =(PoolableConnection)connection.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

But then I am getting error.

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection
```

Can anyone suggest here what are the changes required to pass through this typecasting issue in order to get Poolable Connection from Pool Guard Connection Wrapper. I am new to dbcp2 and need guidance to proceed further.

Thanks in Adavance.

Update- I tried a way to unwrap the PoolGuardWrapper

```
Connection connection = stmt.getConnection();
            
            Connection unwarppedConnection= connection.unwrap(Connection.class);

            PoolableConnection poolConn = (PoolableConnection)((DelegatingConnection<Connection>) unwarppedConnection).getInnermostDelegate();
```

OracleConnection nativeConnection = (OracleConnection) poolConn;

But it throwing below error

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. below are the changes that I made to my code.

```
CallableStatement stmt;
Connection connection = stmt.getConnection();
Connection updatedConnection =((DelegatingConnection) connection).getInnermostDelegate();

OracleConnection nativeConnection = (OracleConnection) updatedConnection;
```

I can see the DB transaction now. Let me know If anything I am doing in a wrong way.